# splitting Swift string complex

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to split a response which is in plain string. Response is as

```
Result Set, Status: N/A Host: somesite.com is Connection live: true Status Connection: deny heart beat: dead
```

Need to create a dictionary from this response like, `ResultSetDic[String:String]`

```
Status: N/A  
Host: somesite.com  
is Connection live: true  
Status Connection: deny  
heart beat: dead
```

tried splitting the response string with various ways Like NSRegularExpression, Range, Split but none of them is cleaner and working multiple string result sets to parse one by one which is not neat.

Any helpful way to split the response in a dictionary.
In above response keys are always fixed.

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? Do they have any machine parsable API available? (JSON, XML, YAML, etc.?)

Comment: Nope this data is send by a server but in an string format. (Not JSON, i wish it was)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a fixed format you're parsing, with known keys, and the same format every time, this is a ready made problem for Regular Expressions:

```
let input = "Result Set, Status: N/A Host: somesite.com is Connection live: true Status Connection: deny heart beat: dead"

extension String {
    subscript(range:NSRange) -> Substring {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
        let end = index(start, offsetBy: range.length)

        return self[start..<end]
    }
}

func parse(response:String) -> [String:String]? {
    guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "Result Set, Status: (.*) Host: (.*) is Connection live: (.*) Status Connection: (.*) heart beat: (.*)", options:[]) else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let match = regex.firstMatch(in: input, range:NSRange(input.startIndex..<input.endIndex, in: input)) else {
        return nil
    }

    // Note that a much better approach here would be to *not* return
    //  a dictionary, but instead to return a struct containing all
    //  of the relevant data
    return [
        "Status": String(input[match.range(at: 1)]),
        "Host": String(input[match.range(at:2)]),
        "is Connection live": String(input[match.range(at:3)]),
        "Status Connection": String(input[match.range(at: 4)]),
        "heart beat": String(input[match.range(at:5)])
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing what makes this parsable is, that each `value` is only a single `word` and that `key` and `value` are separated by `:`.

First I identify the the end of the next key, then add the next word as its value.

```
func testing() {
    let input = "Result Set, Status: N/A Host: somesite.com is Connection live: true Status Connection: deny heart beat: dead"

    var  step1 = input.split(separator: " ")
    guard let index = step1.firstIndex(where: { $0.contains(",") }) else {
        fatalError("Does not contain `,`. at the beginning.")
    }
    step1.removeFirst(index + 1)

    var step2 = step1
    var output = [String: String]()
    repeat {
        guard let index = step2.firstIndex(where: { $0.contains(":") }) else {
            // If the last part has no :, can add it under `end`.
            // output["end"] = step2.joined(separator: " ")
            step2.removeAll()
            break
        }
        let key = step2[0...index].joined(separator: " ").trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ":"))
        let value = step2[index + 1]
        output [key] = String(value)
        step2.removeFirst(index + 2)

    } while step2.count != 0

    output.forEach{
        print("\($0.key): \($0.value)")
    }
}


// Output:
// Host: somesite.com
// Status Connection: deny
// Status: N/A
// heart beat: dead
// is Connection live: true
```

Edit: `Array.firstIndex(where:)` seems to be Xcode10+, so in Xcode9.4 you may try:

```
extension Array {
    func firstIndex(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Int? {
        for index in indices where try predicate(self[index]) { return index }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Edit2: A backward-compatible way to add `.firstIndex(where:)` from Leo:

```
extension Collection {
    func firstIndex(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Index? {
        return try index(where: predicate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Purpose. I'm unable to see step1.firstIndex. Gettting error in Playground            
string-operations.playground:161:27: error: value of type '[String.SubSequence]' (aka 'Array<Substring>') has no member 'firstIndex'
        guard let index = step1.firstIndex(where: { $0.contains(":") }) else {

Comment: change it `index(of:)` and `index(where:)`

Comment: @iamMobile The function seems to have been added in Xcode10/Swift4.2, try the extension above for an alternative. Or try Leo's tip. I can't find them in the Array docs but they may have removed deprecated/renamed functions from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. However, if i change input string to  
let input = "Result Set, Status: N/A Host: somesite.com is Connection live: true Status Connection: deny heart beat: dead end"  
it fails. (Note i have added 'end' "

Comment: @Purpose this would be a better extension to make your code backward compatible `extension Collection {
    func firstIndex(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Index? {
        return try index(where: predicate)
    }
}`

Comment: String doesn't conform to Array

Comment: @LeoDabus Good point! I hoped Array<Substring> may use it. I added your contribution.

Comment: @iamMobile Just comment out `output["end"] = step2.joined(separator: " ") ` so it does not add trailing words which do not conform to the format.

Comment: @Purpose better to use the array indices property to iterate through it. `for index in indices where try predicate(self[index]) {
           return index 
        }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Damn this makes things short, very nice!

Comment: @LeoDabus, can you edit the above code for your sugestion please.

Comment: @iamMobile your edit seems fine. I would just change the return type to Index and extend the Collection instead

Answer (score 1):

Since you have fixed keys and response format, it might be better go with specific parsing logics with your keys.

```
let response = "Result Set, Status: N/A Host: somesite.com is Connection live: true Status Connection: deny heart beat: dead"

enum ResponseParseId: String {
    case status = "Status:"
    case host = "Host:"
    case isConnectionLive = "is Connection live:"
    case statusConnection = "Status Connection:"
    case heartBeat = "heart beat:"

    var key: String {
        switch self {
        case .status:
            return "Status"
        case .host:
            return "Host"
        case .isConnectionLive:
            return "is Connection live"
        case .statusConnection:
            return "Status Connection"
        case .heartBeat:
            return "heart beat"
        }
    }

    static var allIds: [ResponseParseId] = [.status, .host, .isConnectionLive, .statusConnection, .heartBeat]
}

func getValue(from response: String, for key: ResponseParseId) -> String? {
    let components = response.components(separatedBy: key.rawValue)
    if let substring = components.last?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) {
        let subcomponents = substring.components(separatedBy: " ")
        if let value = subcomponents.first {
            return value
    }
}
return nil
}

func getResponseDictionary(response: String) -> [String: String] {
    var dictionary: [String: String] = [:]
    for id in ResponseParseId.allIds {
        if let value = getValue(from: response, for: id) {
            dictionary[id.key] = value
        }
    }
        return dictionary
    }

let dictionary = getResponseDictionary(response: response)

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Interesting approach! Since unknown keys can't be used anyway it makes sense to define them, makes things more sturdy and easier to use with `-> [ResponseParseID: String]`.